# Connect Ubuntu 22.04 with ThinkPad USB-C Dock

Tags: multiple-monitors, hardware

I would like to connect Ubuntu 22.04 to a ThinkPad USB-C Dock by Lenovo. Can you help? It is not being detected on my computer. Also the support page on the Lenovo website does not indicate Linux support. Can you help?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The docking station per se isn't detected, individual devices are, like the USB hub, HDMI (if something is connected) or Ethernet or...

Comment: Neither the screens, nor the keyboard, nor the mouse are recognized. If I connect through USB-C, the orange light turns to white on the docking device, though, but on my Ubuntu 22.04 notebook, nothing happens.

Comment: sorry, the keyboard and the mouse are working! only the screens are not.

Comment: The external screens are two thinkvision screen2, on both ends using display ports and connected to the docking station.

Comment: Not all USB-C ports support video.

Comment: How do I find out about my USB-C port?

Comment: Check the manufacturer's specifications. If not mentioned then it should be assume it doesn't. https://finddiffer.com/does-usb-c-allow-video-output/

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on the USB-C and purchased a Thinkpad hard dock (jacks into the ZIF connector on back of the laptop).

This worked immediately, Two displays at 4K.